# tooltip not showing on first mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I am using jquery-ui's (1.10.2) tooltip widget and I am experiencing an annoying error.
The tooltip won't show on the first mouseover. It does when I mouseout and re-mouseover and everytime after that. Just not the first time. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<img src="btn-tooltip-info.png" class="tooltip" title="Your text here"/>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(document).on("mouseover", ".tooltip", function(e){
        $(this).tooltip({
            content: function() {
                return $(this).attr('title');
            },
            position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using on() because other processes might dynamically change the html after initial load.
I'm at a loss here, any insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So each time your mouse is over a .tooltip element, you are initializing a tooltip plugin. This is not a good way to use it for sure. But looks like you are searching for kind of delegation for tooltip plugin

Comment: As roasted mentioned, You attach the plugin in the document ready and that plugin will propbaly attach the mouse over events for you.

Comment: Roasted is right ! Just call `$(".tooltip").tooltip({...})` in the `.ready` function. Tooltip will automaticly handle the 'mouseover' event

Comment: @guys, this is not what i said, OP want some delegation for dynamic elements, so he needs to filter it in some way, see Arun's answer

Comment: roasted read my question correctly.Arun's answer works like a charm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because the `tooltip` is triggered on mouseover but when the first mouseover happens there is no tooltip widget associated with the element.

A hack you can use in this scenario is to check if the widget is initialized for the element, if not initialize the widget and then manually trigger the `mouseover` event again

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(document).on("mouseover", ".tooltip", function(e){
        if(!$(this).data('tooltip')){
            $(this).tooltip({
                content: function() {
                    return $(this).attr('title');
                },
                position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" }
            }).triggerHandler('mouseover');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6RJ4g/)

As @roasted suggested you can use the [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-open) method instead of triggering `mouseover`.

Instead of `.triggerHandler('mouseover');` use `tooltip('open');`

Comment: @roasted but it looks like a nasty hack

Comment: Not so nasty, you should use .tooltip('open') instead of triggering handler maybe  http://jsfiddle.net/6RJ4g/2/

Comment: @roasted yes.. i should. forgot about it

Comment: Thanks Arun and roasted. I really appreciate this. Not only did it do the trick, I also understand now that tooltip() does not show the tooltip; it initializes the whole mechanism. That was the error in thinking I made.

Comment: in my case, working with `.triggerHandler('mouseover');` not with `tooltip('open');`