# jQuery-UI tooltip shows after second mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this piece of code:

```
(...)
if (data.hasSentMessages === true){
  $("#sentMessages")
    .parent()
    .removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
} else {
  $("#sentMessages")
    .parent()
    .addClass("ui-state-disabled");
}
```

And then, if element has disabled class, I want to show why is element disabled in jQuery-UI Tooltip. But unfortunately it shows after second mouseover event.
When I read this: [Tooltip not showing on first mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981336/tooltip-not-showing-on-first-mouseover) I create something like this:

```
$("#sentMessages").tooltip({disabled: !($("#sentMessages").parent().hasClass("ui-state-disabled"))});
if($("#sentMessages").data("tooltip") === false){
  $("#sentMessages").tooltip({disabled: !($("#sentMessages").parent().hasClass("ui-state-disabled"))}).triggerHandler("mouseover");
}
```

This condition, if widget is not initialized, should manually triggered mouseover event but unfortunately still it isn't working.
I will be very happy if somebody wants to help me - thank you in advance.

There is a simplified Fiddle: [jsFiddle that shows a problem](http://jsfiddle.net/v7Xnh/2/), there you can see that second tooltip is good but first is like ,,standard" browser tooltip.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Anubhav of course, there is a fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/v7Xnh/2/ It doesn't work like my web but there also you can see that second mouseover works better than first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle, the initialisation of the tooltip happens within the mouseover callback function. This will mean that the tooltip is not created until after the first mouseover event.

Secondarily the mouseover event is built into the way that the jQueryUI tooltip functions. As such, you can remove the mouseover code.

Thirdly, you had mentioned that the tooltip should only display when the parent element has the class `ui-state-disabled`.

See the result on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbtedman/MpnLx/).

```
// construct a tooltip for each sentMessages then listen for the 
// tooltipopen event an evaluate if it should show the tooltip
// or not
$("#sentMessages").tooltip().on('tooltipopen', function(){
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('ui-state-disabled')){
        $(this).tooltip("enable");

    } else {
        $(this).tooltip("disabled");
    }
});

// comment out this line to replicate a non error state
$("#sentMessages").parent().addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

based on your example fiddle: add `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to the mouseover event, see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7Xnh/3/):

Comment: That is not expected behavior - if you see my Fiddle you can see that after second mouseenter event tooltip shows under <a> element, but in app there is a jQueryUI tooltip - and that how I want tooltip will behave. With e.stopImmediatePropagation() everytime I see ,,standard" browser tooltip.

Comment: No, the key was that at the first time tooltip behaves like he wasn't initialize (it shows simply tooltip like you put mouse over ,,oldest" or ,,active" tab over Your first naswer ) on the second it shows proper UI tooltip and before update there is the same - but now I placed initialize tooltip in other place (in mouseenter() of icon which after click shows menu with <a> tags) and it seems to work (it's not a solution but... But it works :) )
Thanks for taking the time on my problem! :)