# Tooltip on mouseover is not working for first time

Tags: jquery, angularjs, tooltip

I have tried so many solution which is given in stackoverflow But its not working for me.

My code:

```
<circle cx="847.1614583333333" cy="336.66666666666663" r="10" 
  id="b63a9673-7f08-4563-96a5-78566a12a15c" 
  onmouseover="hotspot_thumbnail('b63a9673-7f08-4563-96a5-78566a12a15c')" 
  stroke="#000000" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" 
  data-pdf-annotate-id="b63a9673-7f08-4563-96a5-78566a12a15c" 
  data-pdf-annotate-type="fillcircle" aria-hidden="true" 
  transform="scale(0.6) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)" 
  style="cursor: pointer;" 
  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" 
  data-trigger="hover" title="hover"></circle>
```

My tooltip:

```
    function tool(){
         $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            animated: 'fade',
            placement: 'bottom',
            html: true
        });
    }
tool();
```

My angular controller code: 
Inside One function in controller

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.heading_hover = spot.hotspot_hover.split('/').pop()
                    $scope.hover_img = spot.hotspot_hover
                    var annote = document.getElementById(uuid);
                    annote.setAttribute('data-toggle','tooltip')
                    annote.setAttribute('data-placement','bottom')
                    annote.setAttribute('data-trigger','hover')
                    annote.setAttribute('title','hover')
                    $("#"+$scope.uuid_hover).tooltip({ content: '<img src="'+$scope.hover_img+'">' }); 

                })
                tool();
```

On first hover its not working but in second hover its working fine.

I have tried this :

[tooltip not showing on first mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981336/tooltip-not-showing-on-first-mouseover)

[Javascript tooltip only appears on second hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266557/javascript-tooltip-only-appears-on-second-hover)

Comment: And what happened when you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981336/tooltip-not-showing-on-first-mouseover - also where do you call the tooltip? You need to call it when the page loads, not in some other event

Comment: am calling from angular controller

Comment: You are aware that .tooltip( is NOT showing the tooltip, only initialising it? So you need to call .tooltip( when you load the page and not on some mouse event

Comment: Am calling the tool(); when page loads